# Is there a standalone tool to generate Entity Framework code first entities from an existing database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-design, poco

I want the ability to generate POCO entities outside of Visual Studio. Is this possible?

Comment: code-first from an existing database doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: From an existing database, it would be model-first :)

Comment: there is a reverse engineer code from existing DB. It makes perfect sense to me. havent seen a standalone version sorry. just this http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a standalone tool (outside of Visual Studio), but I've used the Visual Studio extension [EntityFramework Reverse POCO Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838) on a previous project when switching from Database First / Model First to Code First.

Why does it need to be a standalone tool? You could remove the extension after the conversion if it's a permanent switch.

Comment: Goal was to be able to work outside of Visual Studio but get some level of automation especially when it came to "reverse engineering" large tables. Of course I could do it in VS then use the generated assemblies afterwards but wanted to skip that step.

Answer (score 1):

EntityDeveloper by DevArt. Nice with UI and strong on updating the model, too. Sadly not free, but then not exactly expensive either.

Comment: Brilliant find! Well worth the price! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but it's an issue I'm facing myself currently.

I've managed to have some luck by using EdmGen.exe which is included with in .net4 framework installations, so it's most probably present on client machines.
EdmGen will generate Model and Mapping files and, in addition, you can Generate Object-Layer code with it.

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\edmgen.exe" /mode:fullgeneration /c:"Data Source=<DATASOURCE>; Initial Catalog=<CATALOG>; Integrated Security=SSPI" /project:<PROJECT> /entitycontainer:<ENTITY CONTAINER> /namespace:<NAMESPACE> /language:CSharp
```

After this you can go ahead a generate your Object-Layer code:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\edmgen.exe" /mode:EntityClassGeneration /incsdl:.\<PROJECT>.csdl /outobjectlayer:.\<PROJECT>.Objects.cs /language:CSharp
```

Obviously, you'll want to replace the <*> with your particular needs.
You can also replace \Framework\ with \Framework64\ in the path if you're on a 64-bit machine.

You can read up on all of the features here:
[EDM Generator Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/edm-generator-edmgen-exe)

I've managed to get it working, but the performance has been deplorable. I'm working with a somewhat complex database with about 80 tables and 30-40 views and the fullgeneration took over an hour. I've seen other similar cases online, but haven't found a solution.

EDIT: I just ran into [this excellent tutorial/article](https://liiw.blogspot.com/2014/12/sqlite-entity-framework-database-first.html) which helps automate the whole process. Hope this helps!